# Using grid how do I not have frames push each other out of place

Tags: python-3.x, layout, tkinter, grid, frame

Been working on this problem for more than a day.

I would like for my top frames to be right up against the picture.

When I don't include section 2 frames below the northern frame it works out nicely.
I have looked up and tried using column_configure, tried weight. 
Honestly I am probably using them wrong.

I know there are fixes, here, but its not yet clicking in my mind on how to make it work.

[image: The way I would like, top frames to remain]

[image: How the next section pushes top frame.]

If possible could you not use CLASSES or to many fancy FUNCTIONS.
Honestly at this stage I am weak in them at the moment.
Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and for any assistance offered.

```
from tkinter import *

import os
import PIL.Image
import random
import sys
import tkinter as tk

global logo
global po

# path to image file
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
dt = desktop_top = os.path.join(home,'Desktop')
p3p = python_3_projects = os.path.join(dt,'Python 3 Projects')
ilfru = images_labeled_for_reuse = os.path.join(p3p,'Images Labeled for Reuse')
gp = gurps_path = os.path.join(ilfru,'GURPS')
gg = gurps_gif = os.path.join(gp,'GIF')

fc = 1
# Count number of file in GURPS/GIF folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gg):
    for filenames in files:
        fc +=1

# Pick a random number based off number of files
rn = random.randint(1,fc)

# Cycle through files and assign the random file to logo
fc = 1
# Count number of file in GURPS/GIF folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gg):
    for filenames in files:
        if fc == rn:
            logo = os.path.join(gg,filenames)
        fc +=1

# Get Image Size
# po PIL Open
po = open(logo,"rb")
img = PIL.Image.open(po)

# Image Width, Image Height
iw,ih = img.size

ih = ih + 5

root = tk.Tk()

# Round Down Nearest tenth
def rd(num,divisor):
    x = (num/divisor)-(num%divisor)
    x = int(x)
    return x

# Get Screen Dimensions
sh = screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
sw = screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()

# Window size
rg = str(sw)+'x'+str(sh)
root.geometry(rg)

# Create all frames
nwfh = rd(sh, 10)
nwfw = rd(sw, 4)

equal_sides = nwfh + nwfw
equal_sides = rd(equal_sides,4)

ntf = rd(sw-equal_sides,1)

# Frames

spacer_width = rd(equal_sides,10)

frame0 = Frame(root,bg='black',width=sw,height=sh,padx=5,pady=5)
frame0.grid(row=0,column=0)

north_west_top_frame = Frame(frame0, bg='cyan', width=equal_sides, height=equal_sides)

frame_spacer0 = Frame(frame0, bg='beige', width=spacer_width, height=ih)

northern_top_frame = Frame(frame0,bg='alice blue', width=ntf,height=ih,padx=15,pady=15)

# Layout all frames

# Trying configure
# northern_top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)


# Frame Section 1
north_west_top_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nw")

frame_spacer0.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

northern_top_frame.grid(row=0,column=2)


# Put logo in nw frame
glogo = tk.PhotoImage(file=logo)
gurps_logo = tk.Label(north_west_top_frame, compound = tk.CENTER, text='GURPS\nCHARACTER\nSHEET',fg = "red", font="Helvetica 10 bold", image=glogo).grid(row=0,column=0)

l1 = tk.Label(northern_top_frame, anchor='w', text="Name: ", font = "Helvetica 10 bold",width=17)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
e1 = Entry(northern_top_frame)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

# Spacer Width = pic prame width -
# ih is northern frame height
# need label height

spacer_height = ih-30

# spacer
# s1 = Frame(northern_top_frame,bg='firebrick', width=ntf,height=spacer_height)
# s1.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=11, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)


l4 = tk.Label(northern_top_frame, anchor='w', text="Ht: ", font = "Helvetica 10 bold", width=17)
l4.grid(row=2, column=0)
e4 = Entry(northern_top_frame)
e4.grid(row=2,column=1)



l9 = tk.Label(northern_top_frame, anchor='w', text="Appearance: ", font = "Helvetica 10 bold", width=17)
l9.grid(row=4, column=0)
e9 = Entry(northern_top_frame)
e9.grid(row=4,column=1, columnspan=11, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

# Section 2
s2 = Frame(frame0,bg='firebrick', width=ntf)
s2.grid(row=5,column=0, sticky="w")


l10 = tk.Label(s2, text="LEVEL")
l10.grid(row=6,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code, and try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. For example, we don't need a couple dozen blank lines at the top and bottom, and we probably don't need functions like `rd`  or a couple dozen labels, if your problem is simply with making a frame align with an image.

Comment: Will try to edit out most blank spaces

Comment: Please try to do a bit more than that. We don't need all your code, we only need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Will this work or should I cut more?

Comment: I cut it down as much as I thought was good, leaving the rd and random functions in. Because when I tried to run code without it it broke it more. I trust your judgement, I tended to fall into am I cutting too much or not enough. camp no matter what I tried.

Comment: Hi Warbit. What Bryan is asking for is just a few widgets. Just enough to show the problem. For example based on the images you showed us I would say no more than 3 or  4 labels and no more than 3 or 4 entry fields and the frames you have used. This will be enough to show the problem without loads of code to go through.

Comment: Think I got it. Hopefully that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem basically boils down to this: the beige and white frames are pushed to the right by the red frame, although there is enough room right next to the cyan frame

[image]

The [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this could be as simple as:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame0 = Frame(root, bg='black', width=500, height=300, padx=5, pady=5)
frame0.grid(row=0, column=0)


north_west_top_frame = Frame(frame0, bg='cyan', width=150, height=150)
frame_spacer0 = Frame(frame0, bg='beige', width=50, height=150)
northern_top_frame = Frame(frame0, bg='alice blue', width=300, height=150)

north_west_top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
frame_spacer0.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
northern_top_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)


s2 = Frame(frame0, bg='firebrick', width=500, height=150)
s2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

---

The problem here is how you define the grid. You put both `north_west_top_frame` and `s2` in column 0, the leftmost column. The you put `frame_spacer0` one column to the right and `northern_top_frame` one column further than that. Every column stretches to fit everything you put in it, so the first column (column 0) gets as wide as `s2`. The next column, with the beige frame, is next to the first column, so it will start where the red frame ends.

What you seem to want is that the red frame is not only in column 0, but also in column 1 and 2, under the beige and white frames. To do that use `columnspan`:

```
s2.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="w")
```

When you do this you see the red frame spans all the way across the cyan, beige and white frames:

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome answer. It's great that you took the time to boil the problem down to its essence, and provided a nice screenshot. You might want to include a screenshot produced by the code in the answer for comparison.

Comment: Thank you sooo much you fixed it.

Comment: Yeah Bryan is right, you explained it so well that even my old mind could understand. Thanks again. Onto my next issue. (progress !!) :)

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the kind words. I just added an "after" screenshot.

Comment: @Warbit You're welcome and I'm glad I could help. And besides helping you understand the tkinter `grid` more, I also hope my answer gives you insight in how to make a [mcve]. As you can see I used a lot less code than you while still showcasing the problem, I cut out everything that is unrelated to the problem you were having. Understanding how to make this helps tremendously in asking questions that are easier for other people (and sometimes even yourself) to answer.